# One Thread Using Multiple RemoteDatabase Object

Tags: java, arcadedb

I use OrientDD and exploring ArcadeDB. I have gone through [Java APi (Remote)](https://docs.arcadedb.com/#Java-API-Remote) and understand that that a RemoteDatabase object is not thread safe.

Also as I understand from the source code of [RemoteDatabase](https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/blob/main/network/src/main/java/com/arcadedb/remote/RemoteDatabase.java#L473), a session is initialized when the begin() is called and closed when the commit() is called.

Also I understand that ArcadeDB uses thread local for some purpose but could not find any documentation related to that.

My question is if a thread used more than one RemoteDatabase and calls the begin/commit separately, is there any implication from thread local perspective.

In OrientDB if a thread uses more than one ODatabaseSession, then activateOnCutrrent() thread needs to be called before again using the first session due to thread local reference setting. I didn't find any method equivalent to activateOnCurrent thread.

Is there any thread local level implication in ArcadeDB to use more than one RemoteDatabase in one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcadeDB the `RemoteDatabase` is not threadsafe. It's designed to be used by one thread only. You can have N RemoteDatabase objects, one per thread, or you can pool them.

The RemoteDatabase API doesn't use ThreadLocal. That's used only in the LocalDatabase implementation.

I understand probably it would be better to have one uniform API, namely making RemoteDatabase thread-safe by using ThreadLocal like with the LocalDatabase API. If this is the case for you, please open a new issue on ArcadeDB GitHub. For now, using one instance per thread is the right way to go.

Comment: The current implementation of RemoteDatabase is fine, that is it should not be shared between threads in standard implementation these would be pooled and one thread retrieves and uses then and returns to pool. My question was whether more than one RemoteDatabase object can be used in one thread. From the above, the answer would be yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, the RemoteDatabase keeps the session id, no thread local is involved. So you can use multiple instances in the same thread.